# Desktop disappears if creating new .desktop file in /usr/share/xsessions

Tags: unity, lightdm

I wanted to create my own second session in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by adding a second .desktop file in /usr/share/xsessions which in this instance I called test.desktop.

I kept the same information as was stored in ubuntu.desktop

```
cd /usr/share/xsessions
cat test.desktop
```

And we get:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This sessions logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=unity
Icon=
Type=Application
DesktopNames=Unity
```

I then log out of current session and into my 'test' session and my desktop won't load - I only see my wallpaper and desktop icons. I assumed this simple change would just work but I've obviously overlooked a config setting somewhere. I know of lightdm.conf but that allows me to change 'default session' behaviour and it doesn't look like I would need to add anything specific to get the desktop to work.

```
unity --debug
```

This forces some functionality of the desktop back into action (I get the Ubuntu sidebar back). It also shows several warnings and errors such as:

```
WARN unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher
ERROR unity.glib.dbus.server GlibDBusServer.cpp:538 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR unity.glib.dbus.server GlibDBusServer.cpp:538 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.unity'
```

There are more than I can copy if needed but this is from a different machine.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?
Cheers in advance for any insight you can provide.

Comment: My first guess is that it's because your session is not recognized as one for which a bunch of the things in /etc/xdg/autostart should be started (for example, they specify `OnlyShowIn=Unity;` or `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;LXDE;Unity;` in *their* `.desktop` files).

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the suggestion. Many of the application .desktop files do specify `OnlyShowIn=Unity;` however I would have thought as my second .desktop file also contains `DesktopNames=Unity` that this criteria would be satisfied? As a sanity check I changed `DesktopNames=Unity` in the original Ubuntu.desktop file to see if it "broke" the desktop in the same way but the original session still boots without issue.